# Need some help solving errors in a PHP Treeview (populated with SQL)

Tags: php, sql, treeview

I've tried implementing a treeview on a website but I'm having some errors atm the moment and I can't point out what's causing them, perhaps someone can shed some light on the situation for me.

I've got the folowing table:

```
CREATE TABLE Rubriek(
rubrieknaam     char(50)        not null, /* char(24) */
rubrieknummer   numeric(38)     not null, /* numeric(3) */
rubriek         numeric(38)     null, /* numeric(3) */
volgnr          numeric(38)     not null, /* nuemric(2) */
constraint pk_rubrieknummer primary key(rubrieknummer),
constraint fk_rubriek foreign key(rubriek) references Rubriek (rubrieknummer)
)
```

rubrieknaam -> name of the category
rubrieknummer -> id of the category
rubriek -> tells us if a category is a subcategory, if not then the value will be null

I've filled it with the following testdata:

```
    Rubrieknaam          | rubrieknummer | rubriek
    (= Name of Category) | (=Category ID)| (=Category is a subcategory of the following category):
     ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Cars                | 1             | Null
     Audio               | 2             | Null
     Ford                | 3             | 1 (subcategory of Cars)
     Toyota              | 4             | 1 (subcategory of Cars)
     Speakers            | 5             | 2 (subcategory of Audio)
     Microphones         | 6             | 2 (subcategory of Audio)
     Instruments         | 7             | Null
     Guitar              | 8             | 7 (subcategory of Instruments)
```

I've implemented the following code functions.php:

```
   <?php
function connection($sql){
ini_set('display_errors',true);
$serverName = "WHS\sqlexpress";
$uid = "sa";
$pwd = "projectgroep37";
$databaseName = "EenmaalAndermaal";

//connection to SQL Database
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,
"PWD"=>$pwd,
"Database"=>$databaseName);

//Connecting with SQL Authentication
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);


    $qry = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    $rs = sqlsrv_fetch_array($qry, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH);
    return $rs;
}
function hasChild($rubriek)
  {  
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM Rubriek WHERE rubriek = ' " . $rubriek . " ' ";
    $rs = connection($sql);
    return $rs['count'];
  }

  function CategoryTree($list,$parent,$append)
  {
    $list = '<li>'.$parent['rubrieknaam'].'</li>';

    if (hasChild($parent['rubrieknummer'])) // check if the id has a child
    {
      $append++; // this is our basis on what level is the category e.g. (child1,child2,child3)
      $list .= "<ul class='child child".$append." '>";
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM Rubriek WHERE rubriek = ' " . $parent['rubrieknummer'] . " ' ";

      $child = connection($sql);
      do{
        $list .= CategoryTree($list,$child,$append);
      }while($child = connection($sql));
      $list .= "</ul>";
    }
    return $list;
  }
  function CategoryList()
  {
    $list = "";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Rubriek WHERE (rubriek = 0 OR rubriek IS NULL)";
    $parent = connection($sql);
    $mainlist = "<ul class='parent'>";
    do{
      $mainlist .= CategoryTree($list,$parent,$append = 0);
    }while($parent = connection($sql));
    $list .= "</ul>";
    return $mainlist;
  }
?>
```

functions.php is then included on the webpage (on top). Then I echo the following function in the div I want it to be:

```
 <?php echo CategoryList(); ?>
```

I'm getting the following errors:
The page now just keeps loading but nothing is appearing on the screen.

I'm probably making some newbie mistakes but some help would be much appreciated

Comment: Those look like they're all variable scope issues - you need to pass variables in to functions, otherwise the code inside a function can't 'see' those variables.

Answer (score 0):

Variable $conn is defined outside the function. Inside the function it is not visible, even though it was defined earlier. You can do any of these options:

- pass $conn as a parameter to the function.

  function CategoryList($conn)
  {
     ....
  }
- define $conn as a global variable inside the function you need it

  function CategoryList()
  {

  global $conn;
     ...

  }

Comment: I've tried adding global $conn; to the functions but it gave me a fatal error because the loading time was longer than 300 seconds.

Comment: this is a completely different issue. it means that the errors you mentioned are solved. to solve the new issue check http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: if this helped you, please accept the answer and open a new one for any different issue